# struts2 optiontransferselect retrieve and display value from database

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp, struts2

In the jsp page, I have a `<s:optiontransferselect>` for swap values between left side and right side and a submit button to save.

```xml
<s:optiontransferselect 
    allowUpDownOnLeft="false"
    allowUpDownOnRight="false"
    allowSelectAll="false"
    allowAddAllToLeft="false"
    allowAddAllToRight="false"
    addToRightLabel="Go to right"
    addToLeftLabel="Go to left" 
    leftTitle="Left side values"
    headerKey="0"
    name="option"
    list= "optionList"
    rightTitle="Right side values"
    doubleHeaderKey="0"
    doubleList="selectedOptionList" 
    doubleName="selectOption"
    doubleId="selectedValues"
>
</s:optiontransferselect>

<s:submit />
```

I run the program, it actually can save the value from the right side. However it does not show the saved values there.

I am thinking about using javascript and use `onchange` event in `<s:optiontransferselect>` to achieve this

```
<script>
    function show(){
        const list = document.getElementById("selectedValues");
        for (var i = 0; i < list.options.length; i++) {
        //seems something not correct in this part but I am not sure how solve in this way 
            list.options[i].selected = true;
        }
        return true;
    }
</script>

<s:optiontransferselect 
    allowUpDownOnLeft="false"
    allowUpDownOnRight="false"
    allowSelectAll="false"
    allowAddAllToLeft="false"
    allowAddAllToRight="false"
    addToRightLabel="Go to right"
    addToLeftLabel="Go to left" 
    leftTitle="Left side values"
    headerKey="0"
    name="option"
    list= "optionList"
    rightTitle="Right side values"
    doubleHeaderKey="0"
    doubleList="selectedOptionList" 
    doubleName="selectOption"
    doubleId="selectedValues"
    onchange ="show()" <!-- onchange seems not work here -->
> 
</s:optiontransferselect>
```

When I run the program, the right side still cannot show the saved value.

More information about the optiontransferselect in case it is useful.

I have an action class for it.

```java
public class OptionTransferSelectAction extends ActionSupport {
    private List<String> optionList;
    private List<String> selectedOptionList;
    //private String option;
    private  List<String> option;
    private List<String> selectOption;

    public OptionTransferSelectAction (){
        optionList=new ArrayList<String>();
        //display on the left side for selection
        optionList.add("Section A");
        optionList.add("Section B");
        optionList.add("Section C");
        optionList.add("Section D");
        optionList.add("Section E");
        optionList.add("Section F");
        optionList.add("Section G");
        optionList.add("Section H");

        selectedOptionList=new ArrayList<String>();
        //display on the right side
        //pretend it does not have any values in the first time (does not 
        //trigger the save yet)
        
    }   

    public List<String> getOptionList() {
        return optionList;
    }

    public void setOptionList(List<String> optionList) {
        this.optionList = optionList;
    }

    public List<String> getSelectedOptionList() {
        return selectedOptionList;
    }

    public void setSelectedOptionList(List<String> selectedOptionList) {
        this.selectedOptionList = selectedOptionList;
    }
    /*
    public String getOption() {
        return option;
    }

    public void setOption(String option) {
        this.option = option;
    }
    */
    public List<String> getOption() {
        return option;
    }

    public void setOption(List<String> option) {
        this.option = option;
    }


    public List<String> getSelectOption() {
        return selectOption;
    }

    public void setSelectOption(List<String> selectOption) {
        this.selectOption = selectOption;
    }
}
```

**update**

I change option from  `String` to `List<String>` with the proper getter and setter. I run the code, the `optiontransferselect` still cannot show the saved values.

Which part I did wrong? Would someone let me know please? Thank you.

**update**
I created a new jsp for example, success.jsp. If I selected some values to selectOption and click the submit button. the jsp file can display the values that I just submitted. I can see the saved values in the database. However the optiontransferselect still cannot show the saved values.

The success.jsp has one code which can display the value I have just submitted.

```js
Selected Value(s) : <s:property value="selectOption"/>
```

In the database, I can see the saved values, so I would like to know how to let the `optiontransferselect` show the saved values?

**another update**

I try to use a button to call javascript function to show  `selectedValues` before submit.

```js
<script>
    function testshow() {
        var value = document.getElementById("selectedValues");
        for(var i=0;i<value.options.length; i++) {
            alert(value.options[i].innerHTML);
        }
        return true;
    }
</script>

//button to call the function
<s:submit onclick="return testshow()"/>
```

I run the program, when I click the button, it can show the selected values before submit, so I still don't understand why the `optiontransferselect` cannot get saved selected values.

Comment: One is a string and second is a list.?

Comment: @AleksandrM, both are `ArrayList<String>()`

Comment: @AleksandrM, I updated the content and I would like express my idea about the `optiontransferselect`here. However I haven't use it before, if my idea is not correct or not possible to implement, would you please let me know, thank you,

Comment: @AleksandrM, the `optionList=new ArrayList<String>();` is the left side `optiontransferselect`, it contains values for user to choose and move to the right side. The `selectedOptionList=new ArrayList<String>();` is the right side `optiontransferselect`, if the user move from the optionList, it displays here, and it can the value to optionList. I mean values can swap between left side and right side. The submit button will save the right side box values, I try to make the box show the saved values when the jsp page is open

Comment: But `name`-s are not.

Comment: @AleksandrM, thanks for your reply. I change option from  `String` to `List<String>` with the proper getter and setter. I run the code, the `optiontransferselect` still cannot show the saved values. Would you please let me know my mistake? Thank you very much.

Comment: @AleksandrM, I created a new jsp for example, success.jsp. If I selected some values to `selectOption` and click the submit button. the jsp file can display the values that I just submitted. I can see the saved values in the database. However the `optiontransferselect` still cannot show the saved values.

Comment: @AleksandrM, I try to use a button to call javascript function to show  selectedValues before submit (please see the new edit). I click the button and it can show selected values before submit so I still don't understand why the `optiontransferselect` cannot get saved selected values. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @AleksandrM, it still not working, do you have ideas? Thanks a lot.

Comment: As I understand your question, the problem is on the displayed page only? In that case could you provide the rendered HTML/javascript (only the relevant parts)

Comment: I created a project on GitHub to demonstrate the usage as lined out in my answer: https://github.com/nineninesevenfour/struts2-demo

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two things you need to know in order to solve your issue:

1. The lifetime of a Struts action.
2. How the `optiontransferselect` actually works.

---

### Lifetime of a Struts Action

I start with that, because that might already solve your issue.

***A new instance of a Struts action is created for each request.***

That means for you when connect the attributes `list` (left side) and `doubleList` (right side) to fields in a class derived from `ActionSupport` - like in the example `OptionTransferSelectAction` above - you must ensure, that you initialize it with meaningful values, I mean values that reflect the current state you want to show to the user. In the worst case you have to fetch the values from the database *with each request*.

Alternatively you can inject a bean into the action with a dedicated lifetime (e.g. session scoped). I might line that out in a separate post.

(BTW I would be thankful if someone else could provide further information, if the lifetime of a Struts action can be changed directly).

---

### How `optiontransferselect` works

This tag wraps up two [`select`](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/select-tag.html) tags (or more specifically [`updownselect`](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/updownselect-tag.html) tags). I will line out the function of it first, because it makes us better understand `optiontransferselect`. (*Sidenote*: Contrary to JSF, Struts clearly distinguishes between attributes for get and set operations.)

To connect the `select` tag with the underlying data, these are the three relevant attributes:

1. `list` - This is the list of *all available* values (=get).
2. `value` - This is the list of values *initially selected* (=get).
3. `name` - The name of the property (field) of the action where the *selected values* will be supplied on form submit (=set).

So the only property your action will recieve is the one connected with `name`. The `select` tag will NOT...

- ...post back the complete list of values (the value of `list`) to the action.
- ...change the values of `list` and `value` in the underlying Java class / action.

And the same is true for `optiontransferselect`. Which makes the semantics quite weird, because some changes (namely which values show up left and which show up right) will never be post back to the Struts action, you only can get hold of the ***selected*** values of both sides.

The major difference is that you have those three attributes now twice:

1. list --> `list` for the left and `doubleList` for the right side.
2. value --> `value` for the left and `doubleValue` for the right side.
3. name --> `name` for the left and `doubleName` for the right side.

The question now is how to come by that you will only get the *selected* values? I would suggest to automatically select them right before submission:

```html
<s:submit value="Save" onclick="selectAllOptions(document.getElementById('idLeft'));selectAllOptions(document.getElementById('idRight'));"/>
```

Where `idLeft` corresponds to the value of `id` in the optiontransferselect and `idRight` corresponds to the value of `doubleId`. With that change you would get the complete list of left and right values in `name` and `doubleName` respectively.

The code is exactly the same as for the button you would get with `allowSelectAll="true"` and the JavaScript method `selectAllOptions` is provided by Struts via the `optiontransferselect.js`, regardless of allowSelectAll was true or false.

Comment: PS: A tag that would provide selection semantics just by moving values from left to right (it could be named e.g. selectByTransfer) seems not to be provided by Struts - at least I did not find it.

Comment: Approach from answer tested with struts version 2.5.26, JDK 11 and jetty-maven-plugin 10.0.3.